# How to increase number of search terms in Tweepy for Twitter API access?

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I found that I can only include up till 20+ search terms with the following code, then it gives me error of saying there is too many search terms. Is there any way to get around it?

```
import tweepy
searchTerms = '1' or '2' or '3' # to say ... '99' or '100'
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerms, since=startSince, until=endUntil).items()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Twitter [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets), the `q` parameter is limited.

> A UTF-8, URL-encoded search query of 500 characters maximum, including operators. Queries may additionally be limited by complexity.

If you want to build complex search term logic you could use a [Streamer](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html) and Listener.  You're essentially doing your own filtering.  Here's a simple example of a Listener.  I tried to give some popular objects returned from the `on_status` method, returned as a `json`.

```
import json

class SListener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, api = None, fprefix = 'streamer'):
        self.api = api or API()
        self.counter = 0
        self.fprefix = fprefix

    def on_data(self, data):
        elif 'limit' in data:
            if self.on_limit(json.loads(data)['limit']['track']) is False:
                return False
        elif 'warning' in data:
            warning = json.loads(data)['warnings']
            print warning['message']
            return false

    def on_status(self, status):

        status_obj = json.loads(status)

        username = status_obj["user"]["screen_name"]
        userID = status_obj["user"]["id"]
        user_loc = status_obj["user"]["location"]
        tweet_date_time = status_obj["created_at"]
        tweetID = status_obj["id"]

        tweet = status_obj["text"].encode('utf-8')
        searchTerms = ['1','2','3'] # to say ... '99' or '100'

        if any(query in tweet for query in searchTerms):
            print(tweet) #or do something with it
```